# How to get value from array? php

Tags: php, zend-framework, sendmail

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Email extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'memberdetail';  

public function sendEmail($email)
{

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $userid = ($this->select('userid')
            ->from('usertable', 'memberdetail')
            ->where('usertable.userid = memberdetail.memberid AND memberdetail.memberid = (SELECT memberid FROM memberdetail WHERE email = ?)', "".$email. "'"));

    $reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
    $reset->resetPass($userid);

    $pswd = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
    $pswd = $pswd->getTemp();

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();

    $mail->setFrom('swap.test@yahoo.com.sg', 'Inexorable Beauty');
    $mail->addTo($email, $email);
    $mail->setSubject('Inexorable Beauty: Password Reset');
    $mail->setBodyText('Dear Customer,

            You have requested to reset your password.
            This is the temporary password: '.$pswd.'

            Please log in immediately and change your password.
            Thank You.

            Yours Sincerely,
            Inexorable Beauty');

    $mail->send();

    if($mail->send())
    {
        echo "Email successfully sent!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Email was not sent";
    }



}
```

I am trying to get the userid which is referenced from the memberid. I can get the memberid through the email which I did $_POST['email']. The problem is, I cant seem to get the value of the userid. I tried to echo the userid through a while loop but it doesnt work. And when I print the SQL, it seems to be of a different statement from what I wrote.

Comment: separation of concerns...is a concern :)

Comment: Question, are you using Zend Framework as a MVC application or are you just using the parts that appeal to you?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subquery = $db->select()
               ->from('memberdetail', array('memberid'))
               ->where('email = ?', $email);

$select = $db->select()
             ->from('usertable', array('userid'))
             ->join('memberdetail', 'usertable.userid = memberdetail.memberid')
             ->where('usertable.userid = ?', $subquery);

$result = $select->query()->fetch();
if (!$result) {
    // user not found
} else {
    $userid = $result['userid'];
}
```

The way you have it right now, `$userid` is just a `Zend_Db_Select` object, but no query is ever executed.  Also, you don't pass any parameters to `select()`, specify the columns you want in the `from()` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. However, the statements does not seem to return me anything. The page gets refreshed when I run the queries.

Comment: Btw, do I need to put "$email" since the email is a string?

Comment: you shouldn't have to put `$email` in quotes in any of the code I have posted above.  ZF will take care of any quoting in the query.